# Jquery mobile loading does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, loading

i want to show loading gif until data loaded with jquery mobile
but it does not work ..in console it give that error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loading'
```

this is my page :[enter link description here](http://t.hybridsoftware.net/p6.htm)

and in this page that  i added code

```
 $.mobile.loading( 'show');
```

and this not work:[enter link description here](http://t.hybridsoftware.net/p1.htm)

my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#details').live('pageinit', function (event) {
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                $("#listeu").empty();
                $.getJSON('http://teknonova.com/Map/Home/getir3/1', function (data) {
```

Comment: how do you call it and when? pls post more relevant info.

Comment: You're using JQM version 1.0 either use `$.mobile.showLoadingMsg();` or upgrade to latest stable version 1.3.2

Comment: Sorry, `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();`.

Comment: @Omar i used $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); but it still give same error ..you can look all code in link..i tried give all code but stackoverflow don t allow

Comment: What version of JQM are you using? Paste the code of how you call the spinner. Nobody would go through all your code and debug it. Pls, help us to help you.

Comment: @omar i added code and edited question.... you can search all page code here... view-source:t.hybridsoftware.net/p3.htm   i want to loading gif when that event called:   $('#details').live('pageinit', function (event) {

Comment: it seems that you have loaded jquert twice in head and below footer. Plus you're using old version of jquery mobile. Place these libraries in head `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>` and remove old jquery and jquery mobile. And then replace `.live` with `.on`.

Answer (score 0):

The error sounds like either the jquery mobile library wasn't loaded properly (maybe loaded before jquery and failed init) or the version of jquery mobile doesn't support that method.

I'd use the dev console to see what the $.mobile object is for more clues

Comment: i added my code to this event:   $('#details').live('pageinit', function (event) {
       this is console screen: http://n1309.hizliresim.com/1f/l/su0hr.png

Comment: It's hard to tell. What happens if you remove that line, and call $.mobile.loading('show') in your console window? I forget if the pageinit event is too early. Maybe try pageshow or pagebeforeshow events instead.